# Wordpress: javascript stopped triggered by span class to be applied on pages stopped to work

Tags: javascript, html

I had a javascript applied to span elements that is adapting the time displayed to the local browser. It was working fine but suddenly stopped to work.

Html on the page:
`<span class="time">18:00</span>`

Javascript:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {

    /*
    var string= location.href;
    var convertedString= string.toLowerCase();
    
    if(convertedString.indexOf('welcome') != -1) {
        if (screen.width > 699) {
        window.location = 'https://souldimension.org/joy-of-breathing/';
        }
    }
    */
    
    var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
    var d;
    var time;
    var hours;
    var minutes;
    var suffix;
    var separator;
    
    const timeArray = document.getElementsByClassName('time');
    const size = timeArray.length;
    if(size>0){
    

for(var i=0;i<size;i++){
    d=new Date();
    time = timeArray[i].innerHTML.split(':');
    hours='';
    minutes='';
    suffix='';
    separator='';
    if(time.length>1){
        d.setMinutes(time[1]);
    } else{
        d.setMinutes(0);
    }
    d.setHours(time[0]);
    d.setSeconds(0);

    /* Ajouter '-60' pour l'heure d'été */
    d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes()-offset-60);
    /*d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes()-offset-0);*/

        if (d.getHours()===12){
            hours=d.getHours();
            suffix='pm';
        }
        else if (d.getHours()>12){
            hours=d.getHours()-12;
            suffix='pm';
        }
        else if (d.getHours()===0){
            hours=12;
            suffix='am';
        }
        else{
            hours=d.getHours();
            suffix='am';
        }
        
    if(d.getMinutes()!==0){
        if(d.getMinutes()<10) {
            minutes='0'+d.getMinutes();
                } else {
            minutes=d.getMinutes();
                }
        separator=':';

    }

    document.getElementsByClassName('time')[i].innerHTML=hours+separator+minutes+suffix;

}
}
}
</script>
```

This is how I include the javascript from the function.php of my child theme:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','collectiveray_load_js_script');
function collectiveray_load_js_script() {
  //if( is_page(ID) ) {
    //wp_enqueue_script('timezone.js', '/wp-content/themes/astra-child/js/', array('jquery'), '', false);
    wp_enqueue_script('timezone', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/timezone.js', array(), false, false);
  //}
}
```

The history:
Everything was working fine until recently. The javascript seems to not be applied anymore.
I tried to de-activate the cache (WP Rocket), but it didn't change anything.

Any idea where the problem could be?

Thanks for helping!
Regards,
Christian

Comment: Are you sure `window.onload` is not overwritten by another script? Try using [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event) instead. -> `window.addEventListener('load', YOUR_FUNCTION);`

Comment: Thanks Reyno! I just tried with this code `document.addEventListener('load', changeTimezone); function changeTimezone() {` but it doesn't change anything. Any other idea?

Comment: The problem was coming from "Facebook for Wordpress" plugin. After I deactivated it, everything works fine again. For info: the code displayed in this page is working fine and can be used if you're interested!